# I get a black screen with Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10 dual boot, only boots in recovery mode

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, graphics, recovery-mode

I get a black screen with Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10 dual boot. Windows 10 boots fine, but Ubuntu 20.04 only boots in  Recovery mode.

I am really trying to give up my Windows life and adopt Linux as OS, but in meanwhile I am having problems with my dual boot. I installed Ubuntu in a different hard drive, more specifically in a partition of my 2TB internal HD. Windows is installed in my internal 256GB SSD. I've had some issues trying to install, many times there were errors in installation, so I followed some instructions to install it without the internet. It worked fine, but now I can't move forward.

grub appears to locate all my boot files, such as Ubuntu in HD and Windows 10 in my SSD, but if I choose Ubuntu (1st option in grub), I get stuck at a black screen. I can run it through recovery mode, after choosing "Ubuntu with advanced options" (the 2nd option in grub ) I don't have experience on that, but right now what I am doing is to do a partial upgrade via Ubuntu in recovery mode.

Details:

My laptop has 2 graphics cards:

1. Intel HD (integrated graphics)
2. Nvidia GeForce 1050 max q designed (discrete graphics)

I checked in the system, and Ubuntu (recovery mode) says that it's using the Nvidia one.

EDI[1]

I have done a clear installation, but at this point I connected a Seagate external HD in which Ubuntu is installed and operating. I am having some problem. I followed the link that a user commented, but it didn't solve my problem. I am still facing issues while booting. Lately I could not boot even through recovery mode. One thing that I did, and it worked, was to add `acpi = off` in grub parameter. Since I did it I could boot twice with no errors. I did this only one time, and could boot 2 times, the last one, I did not add this little code.

I am ran Boot-Repair, and it output this [log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kSVjYwXfpJ/). Boot-Repair finished and generated this other [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pqvGRzVX8R/).

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Warning: failed to translate partition name
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
/usr/share/boot-sav/bs-cmd_terminal.sh: line 177: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will purge (in order to sign-grub) and reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
sdc2,
using the following options:        sdc1/boot/efi,
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix use-standard-efi-file  restore-efi-backups


/boot/efi added in sdc2/fstab
rm /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
rm /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Quantity of real Windows: 1
Mount sdc1 on /boot/efi
apt-get -y update
Purge the GRUB of sdc2
grub-efi-amd64-signed available

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libfprint-2-tod1 libnvidia-cfg1-440 libnvidia-common-440
libnvidia-compute-440 libnvidia-compute-440:i386 libnvidia-decode-440
libnvidia-decode-440:i386 libnvidia-encode-440 libnvidia-encode-440:i386
libnvidia-extra-440 libnvidia-fbc1-440 libnvidia-gl-440
libnvidia-gl-440:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-440 nvidia-compute-utils-440
nvidia-kernel-common-440 nvidia-kernel-source-440 nvidia-utils-440
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
DEBCHECK debOK, grub-efi-amd64-signed
DEBCHECK debOK
shim-signed available
Please type: sudo dpkg --configure -ansudo apt-get install -fynsudo apt-get purge -y grub*-common shim-signed
shim-signed available
linux-headers-generic available
linux-signed-generic NOT available (apt-cache policy  problem)
Then type: sudo apt-get install -y grub-efi-amd64-signed os-prober shim-signed linux-headers-generic
GRUB is still absent. Please try again.

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdc2/etc/default/grub

==== Reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed os-prober shim-signed linux-headers-generic of sdc2 =====

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.4

efibootmgr -v from chroot before grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,0003,0004,0000
Boot0000* ubu   VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7ac1c822-c071-419c-a842-735d0895936f,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,a1b191ce-24b9-4cc7-b895-9b6da5ede189,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,e96f734c-5b2b-45a5-a8b7-92b0dae77bac,0xe5370000,0x135f1b)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,a1b191ce-24b9-4cc7-b895-9b6da5ede189,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)..BO

uname -r
5.4.0-42-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sdc1
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/
df /dev/sda2
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/sdb1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v from chroot after grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,0000
Boot0000* ubu   VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7ac1c822-c071-419c-a842-735d0895936f,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,a1b191ce-24b9-4cc7-b895-9b6da5ede189,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (20.04) on /dev/sda3
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdc2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS CurrentSession entry (sdc1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.

If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

While in recovery mode, either switch to the Intel video card or switch your driver to the propietary NVIDIA driver.  If the proprietary driver is not available you may need to download it.

Comment: Hey Hoat, thanks for your time, 

I can see that Ubuntu is using de nvidia card, I've already donwloaded the nvidea drivers in Additional Drivers, right now I ll try to reinstall folowwing some steps as a user showed. I ll bring you updates

Comment: Also, when I try to do a clean install , from a bootable USB UEFI drive it shows "Instalation crashed"and brings me to this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1871268